# Cross-references and figures doesnt render when knit a pdf, since Rstudio install babel-stuff (after changing language to "fr-FR")

Tags: r, babeljs, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I really need help this time:

*Rstudio auto-install some babel-stuff* after I've indicate the language of an academic paper in YAML (lang: "fr-FR"). *After that point, when I'm knit to pdf, tables and figures doesn't render anymore in the pdf*: computation printed in the text are correct, but the pdf produced is now without figure, without table, and cross-references are not working anymore (e.g., the pdf now contain some "Figure @ref(tab:repartition-transport)" where before the language-change there is a number printed like "Figure 1").

I try to set language back to "en-EN" but cross-references, tables and figures doesn't render in the pdf.

The error message said that, when knitting is over:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language 'French' into the format. 
Avis :    (babel)   Please, configure your TeX system to add them and rebuild the format.
Now I will use the patterns preloaded for \language=nohyphenation instead on input line 87.
```

I don't understand.
Since I don't know how to remove babel (which is not in the packages list), I try to run `tinytex::check_installed("babel")`, which answer: TRUE. Any help is very appreciated, since I don't know what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284168/no-hyphenation-patterns-were-preloaded If it won't help - please add a small example of your rmarkdown. And look here: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/97 Try this command: ```tinytex::tlmgr_install("hyphen-french")```

Comment: The babel warning is a tinytex bug. I'll fix it later today. Before the fix is available, you can `tinytex::tlmgr_install('hyphen-french')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I strongly appreciate your help ! Now I knit without warning about these "hyphen", and cross-references are now working with `pdf_document : bookdown::pdf_document2` in the YAML (with `rmarkdown::pdf_document` cross-references print like that: "Figure ??" and "Table ??").  Thanks again